# how to display image when image tag special?

Tags: html, image

I have a code:

```
<div>&lt;img src=".../media/wysiwyg/ingresso-festa-retro-mix.jpg" &gt;
```

It is not display image. However, when I use <> then it display normally:

```
<div><img src=".../media/wysiwyg/ingresso-festa-retro-mix.jpg">
```

is someone know it?

Comment: you should obey html rules dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jquery without you wont. otherwise if its `jade` or `pug` means you can because they having compiler to compile it into `HTML`. but `DOM` may have some property for `HTML` to render. 
even though < and > will render into `<` `>` but only after DOM.

Sample using jquery,

```js
$('#demo').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var t = $this.text();
    $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">&lt;img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png"&gt;</div>
```